# Insert After in Iframe text editor

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe text editor. For inserting image I have a snippet of code as :

```
.
.
.
  var sel = document.getElementById('wysiwygtextfield').contentWindow.getSelection();
  // get the first range of the selection (there's almost always only one range)
  var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);

  // deselect everything
  sel.removeAllRanges();

  // remove content of current selection from document
  range.deleteContents();

  // get location of current selection
  var container = range.startContainer;
.
.
.
 **afterNode = container.childNodes[0];
 container.insertBefore(insertNode, afterNode);**
 // This does not work
 // container.insertAfter(insertNode, afterNode);
```

The problem lies with the last two lines. I tried using `insertAfter` but it doesn't seem to work. With insert before it inserts before the selected content or the element adjacent to it. Any way to make it insert after. This way it makes it appear as if the user if typing *right to left* instead of *left to right*.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to avoid the use of iframes. Is there a way you can achieve your goal with a div or using AJAX calls with JQuery? This isn't exactly what your talking about but you can use the same idea for your WYSIWYG editor. http://techmeout.org/hacking-joomla/